# Is there any example for: How to use "OASIS Library" in Java to create XLIFF file

Tags: java, localization, document, xliff, oasis

Hello basically I want to use this library to create (XLIFF) files but i'm searching many times but did not find any example for how to use it this is link for [OASIS][1][1]: http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/xliff-core/v2.1/xliff-core-v2.1.html. **OR** if there any library can I use to create XLIFF file example for file :

```
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:2.0" version="2.0"
 srcLang="en-US" trgLang="ja-JP">
 <file id="f1" original="Graphic Example.psd">
  <skeleton href="Graphic Example.psd.skl"/>
  <unit id="1">
    <source>Quetzal</source>
    <target>Quetzal</target>
  </unit>
  <unit id="2">
    <source>An application to manipulate and process XLIFF documents</source>
    <target>XLIFF 文書を編集、または処理 するアプリケーションです。</target>
  </unit>
  <unit id="3">
    <source>XLIFF Data Manager</source>
    <target>XLIFF データ・マネージャ</target>
  </unit>
 </file>
</xliff>
```

Answer (score 1):

Oasis is not a library, but an organization which creates and maintains open standards. The [link](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/xliff-core/v2.1/xliff-core-v2.1.html) you provide is the specification of the XLIFF 2.1 standard.

To create an XLIFF file programmatically using Java, I would recommend the [Okapi Framework](http://okapiframework.org/) and, specifically, its XLIFF toolkit. It is well documented and actively maintained, so you should be able to figure it out based on the documentation and code examples.

(disclaimer: I am one of the committers of the Okapi framework)